# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Tags: java, html, spring, tomcat

This is probably a super simple answer... but for the life of me I can not see what I am missing.

I just have a basic Hello World spring web app. But I can not get any of my resource files to be found. I keep getting a 404.

I have the webapp deployed on a tomcat server running on my computer.

In the .jsp file...

```
<c:url value="/resources/js" var="js"/>
<c:url value="/resources/css" var="css"/>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="${css}/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="${css}/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

    ...

    <script src="${js}/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="${js}/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And it even autocompletes the url when in the IDE so the path has(most likely) to be right.

Structure of it..

```
src
-main
  -java
  -resources
  -webapp
    -resources
       -css
       -fonts
       -img
       -js
    -WEB-INF
       -views
          -index.jsp
```

Also all users have at least read access to the files.

Could there be something with the tomcat server maybe? Or am I just really missing something here?

When I type the file path into the url, I get the 404 as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using badly the c:url

Change

```
<c:url value="/resources/js" var="js"/>
```

to

```
<spring:url value="/resources/js" var="js" />
```

Maybe it help:

https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-how-to-include-js-or-css-files-in-a-jsp-page/

Comment: Just switched and tried and still 404 error. I can see the path its getting and its the same if I use `<c:url...` or `<spring:url...` 

They both print out `<link href="/MyApp/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: When you deploy, what is the url created by the tomcat? and could you put the messages exactly as your browser shows at console?

Comment: Did you see the link of mkyong? There he puts the annotation to resources..

Comment: It goes to https://localhost:8080/MyApp which is just the simple Hello World html page.

Answer (score 0):

"c:url" is a taglib function that reformats urls (add the protocol, servename, port and such). You cannot declare variables with it. Try "c:set" instead:

```
<c:set var="jspVariable" value=${elVariable} />
```

Answer (score 0):

WEB-INF directory is a private area of the web application, any files under WEB-INF directory cannot be accessed directly from the browser by specifying the URL.

You need to put your JSP file one level up the WEB-INF directory